# TypeORM generating correct query but returning no data

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using TypeORM to query a simple `Like´ entity which is defined as follows:

```
@Entity()
export class Like extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(type => Post, post => post.likeList)
    post: Post;

    @ManyToOne(type => Contest, contest => contest.likeList)
    contest: Contest; // Denormalization

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.likeList)
    user: User;
}
```

I need to the select certaing `postId`s based on a where clause, to achieve this I am running the following query using the `repository`

```
const test = await this.repository.find({
                where: {
                    user: userId,
                    contest: contestId,
                },
                select: ['post'],
            });
```

The generated SQL statement - `SELECT "Like"."postId" FROM "like" "Like" WHERE "Like"."userId" = $1 AND "Like"."contestId" = $2 -- PARAMETERS: [3,1]`- produces the following output when ran against my postgres database:

[image]

Interestingly though, the value of `test` is always an empty array...what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can tried

```
const test = await this.repository.find({
                where: {
                    user: userId,
                    contest: contestId,
                },
                relations: ['post'],
            });
console.log('result data: test', test);
return test;
```